# How can I get number of active (non ignored) tests from assembly?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

My issues is about to count number of active tests which would run on CI pipeline. 
Tests are written on .Net with NUnit framework.

My project is on python, so, I cant directly use .Net reflection to do that (except if I'l write the second app which would transfer this data to my main python app, but thats not the case at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the console runner in explore mode and parse the outputs

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line --explore[=SPEC]